# How to Properly Setup a Java Web Applet Using SMTP on a Server

Tags: java, applet, glassfish, web

I need to have a Java web applet send automated emails via SMTP. I am relatively fresh to servers and communication from a programming standpoint. As such, I am not using servlets and am just running the java mail api in my web applet. It runs fine when I run it through Netbeans and am using Glassfish. I want to put it on to a company's server so it can be run from their website.

I know how to embed the applet and such, but I am not sure how the email service will work exactly. From what I understand, I need the appropriate jar files (mail, activation, pop3, etc.) set on the server's classpath, or in a nearby directory while the applet is running. I am supposing this server will do something similar to Glassfish, as I can compile and run everything in the applet outside of netbeans, but get classnotfound/classnotdef errors when the applet attempts to send an email. This would seem due to a lack of a server environment similar to Glassfish.

Again, I am pretty new to this area of server communication and structure, so any guides to help with introductions would be useful. In addition to that, any jump-start advice would also be appreciated to get stuff moving for the time being.

Lastly, what does Glassfish and other services like Apache and Tomcat provide for Netbeans exactly? They seem to be required to developed anything web-related in Netbeans, though I can run applets outside of Netbeans (excluding the mail services), what is it actually doing? Is it a faux server mimicking the processes of a full one? I spent some hours trying to find out more about these things, but there is not a basic how/why for all of this that I have found.

Thank you for any direction.

Comment: *"I know how to embed the applet and such"*  Are you sure of that?  It seems to be negated by.. *"but get classnotfound/classnotdef errors when the applet attempts to send an email"*.  What exact exceptions do you get, and what Jars are those classes (the ones mentioned in the throwables) inside?

Comment: Do you want the client or the server to send the email? Applets run on the client and servlets run on the server - there is a separate class path on each. Would be better sending the email on the server, but harder to setup

Comment: So, all the graphics and regular functions work fine in the applet. When the send message function is called, it spits out the classnotfound/classnotdef errors to the terminal. It's having trouble finding javax/mail/address, which would point to the mail jar. Where would I place that on the server, and do I need to direct the applet to it?

At this point I believe the client is sending the emails. I'm fine with that for now, it's not doing a huge mailing list or anything heavy duty.

Answer (score 1):

> Where would I place that on the server,..

In a place accessible to the JRE.  Some directories of servers are barred to applets (and general browsing), but one place that the JRE should be able to load the Jars from, is the same directory as the HTML.  That is not the most optimal solution, but it will work.

If you wish to go with 'optimal', I'd put all the Jars for all applets in a single directory, `/lib` (a `lib` directory at the root of the public site - mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/lib).

> ..and do I need to direct the applet to it?

Yes. That is done using the `archive` attribute of the applet element.  See [The APPLET Tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html#archive) for further details.

---

Once it is working using a plain applet element, it would be best to then convert to launching using the [deployJava.js](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).  The script does minim version checking for the JRE.  But first get it working using an `applet` element on one machine that already has the minimum needed JRE to run the applet - it is simpler.

---

BTW - this applet will need to be digitally signed and trusted by the end user, before it can send emails to addresses at other domains.  One of the advantages of sending the mail from the server is that the applet could be sand-boxed, since it only needs to 'phone home' in order to send the information - the server does the rest.

---

> Regarding the digitally signature, I have not heard about that being a requirement for sending the mail.

You have a steep learnig curve ahead.  ;)

> Could you explain why it would need to be signed?

See [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

### Unsigned Applets

Unsigned applets can perform the following operations:

- *They can make network connections to the **host they came from**.*
- ...

Quote from Oracle, *emphasis* & **boldness** by me.  One of the reasons this decision was made, was because (then owners) Sun did not want applets getting a bad name by making cross-site requests for resources (me pulling an image directly off your site to show it in an applet on my site).  It is known as hot-linking, & is very frowned upon, since my site is getting the benefit (and visitors) but your site is paying for the resource hosting and the download.

Another reason is that an applet might start up then attack a site, by requesting a single resource thousands of times.  Get a 'kewl' applet game with that happening (hidden in the background) in a thousand browsers and you might be able to cause a site to crash.  It is called a 'Denial of Service' attack.

So Sun decided that an applet could only reach across domains if it had the trust of the user, and the only way to get that trust is for the developer to sign the code, the JRE to ask the user if they will allow it to run, and the user to OK that prompt.

In recent times Sun started to recognize the ..cross-domains.xml (or called something like that).  If you put one of those files at the right name/location on your site, you can signal the JRE that it is OK to *allow access* to resources to applets from other sites (without the user giving explicit permission).

I doubt that would work for email even if the domain to which the mail is sent, had the appropriate file allowing it.  But I have not tested it.

Comment: Thank you, that answers a good bit for me. Regarding the digitally signature, I have not heard about that being a requirement for sending the mail. For the moment, it is just sending text so there is no signature needed for direct file exchange. Additionally, the email is sent from the client if that makes a difference. Could you explain why it would need to be signed?

Comment: See the edit.  But please note it is best (and expected), to keep it to 'one question per topic', as well as 'questions that can be answered quickly/succinctly'.  This Q&A is looking to develop into a saga.  As such, I think you should focus on the class-path alone in this question, and leave digital code signing and trust for other question(s).